# Azure Web App Not Updated Despite Succesful Deployment

Tags: python, flask, azure-devops, flask-sqlalchemy, pipeline

I have deployed a Flask Web App via an Azure DevOps Pipeline. When I commit on the main branch the Pipeline runs successfully and I can see the updated Python files in Kudu Debug Console in the wwwrooot.

However, the app does not reflect the changes. Namely, when I try to access a route via a  get I still receive an old message which has been in the commit one week ago not the latest one.

I have tried to set the app settings:

```
WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0 and 
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION  = Never
```

I have no clue what is wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: A 'shot in the dark' from me (since I'm not well rehearsed with Azure services): do you have a systemd service for the flask app running on your Azure service? If so, maybe try running `systemctl restart yourflaskapp.service`.

Comment: Thanks! what actually helped was remove and then recreating the publishing profile in Azure - really strange. But it helped.